# vb.net function to return an operator

Tags: vb.net

i want the code to return an operator such as (+) or (-)
and then use that to perform a calculation. is that possible in vb.net?

PseudoCode

```
public function rOperator(params) as operator

if (..)
return +

else 
return -
end if

end function
```

PseudoCode

```
Msgbox(1 rOperator 2)
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. The most simple way would be to make a function which calculates differently depending on your condition(s). I.e. `DoMath(1, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said before, that is not possible.  What you can do is create a dictionary of `Func(Of T)` and then invoke those by passing in your operator:

```
Sub Main
    Dim operations As New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))()

    'Set up operations for addition, subtractions, multipication, and division
    operations.Add("+", Function(l, r) l + r)
    operations.Add("-", Function(l, r) l - r)
    operations.Add("*", Function(l, r) l * r)
    operations.Add("/", Function(l, r) l / r)

    Dim result As Double = operations("+")(5, 5)
    Dim result2 As Double = operations("*")(5, 5)

    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.WriteLine(result2)

End Sub
```